# Read a directory to see the file to inode mapping

Tags: filesystems, directory

I'm just learning about filesystems and it is said that a directory is just an ordinary file which keeps a list of file-inode pairs.

If I try to open the directory `Downloads` with any of the following `cat` `less` `tail`, it just outputs that its a directory and can't be opened.

Ideas how to read it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A correction: the directory is a list of fileNAME-inode pairs. And it's not an "ordinary" file. Like symlinks, sockets, and device nodes, its behaviour is different from that of ordinary files.

From the shell, you can see the mapping with `ls -i`.

From C, the structure returned by `readdir()` contains a `d_name` and a `d_ino` element, from which you can also see this mapping.

From userspace, the fact that a directory maps filenames to inodes is not usually all that important, because the kernel requires that you designate files by their name anyway. It doesn't let you ask for a file by inode number.

Symbolic links are another example of a type of file which contains information that can't be read as though it were a byte stream with systems calls like `read()`. Like an ordinary file, it contains data. In this case the data has special meaning: it's a pathname (which is a string) naming the target of the symlink. Unlike an ordinary file, the contents are not written using `write()` but with `symlink()`, and the contents are not read using `read()` but with `readlink()`.

Comment: So there isn't a way to read it through the terminal directly with a command without writing a C program? I would like to see if there is anything else written besides the mappings.

Comment: All of the tools like `cat` for reading regular files use `read()` and similar system calls that assume the file is a stream of bytes. But a directory is not (at least conceptually) as stream of bytes, it's a mapping. The kernel provides systems calls specifically for the purpose of reading this mapping. Tools like `ls` use these system calls. So short answer, yes: to read the contents of a directory, you need a tool designed to read directories.

Comment: If you are curious on the contents of a directory, it is just as is being told here: Filenames and corresponding inode numbers. Plus junk like space where the names of deleted files used to be, space at the end of the filename that use to be called `supercalifragilisticexpialidocious.c` and is now called just `bob.c`, free space to round up to blocksize, ... Nothing to feed your favorite conspiracy theory, in fact. Directories used to be readable as regular files in simpler days, but as the structure became more complicated that is now forbidden.

Answer (score 2):

A directory is just like a file, but the kernel restricts access by only allowing certain system calls to open, read, and write to a directory entry. Here are some examples of the differences in C functions:

```
File      Directory
open()    opendir()
read()    readdir()
write()   N/A
close()   closedir()
```

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on the OS. I don't know the specific explanation but have experienced a difference between Linux and Unix behaviors in this regard. Specifically FreeBSD, you CAN `cat` a directory. Threw me off the first time I tried.