# List only files in a directory and show the inode number

Tags: ls

How can I list all files but not directories in a given directory and show the inode-numbers.

Something like `ls -li | grep ^-` does not work since the inode number is shown in the beginning of the line.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61533/read-a-directory-to-see-the-file-to-inode-mapping

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple solutions.  Assuming you do not have a filename starting with `-`

```
ls -li | grep " -"
ls -li | awk '/ -/'
```

If a directory contains `-`, it can be fixed by

```
ls -li | grep "[0-9][0-9]* -"
ls -li | awk '$2 ~ "-.{9}"'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec ls -li '{}' \;
```

or, to get `ls`-like output:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f  -printf '%i %M %n %u %g %kK %Tc %p\n'
```

Parsing `ls` is a [bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) since it can often lead to trouble.

If you really want to use `ls` directly, you could do this:

```
ls -li | gawk '$2!~/d/'
```

Comment: You might want to use `+` instead of `\;` in your first example (if your version of `find` supports is) so as not to fork too much on `ls`. Might also want to add `\! -name '.*'` so as not to list hidden files.

Comment: Oh, and if you want to parse the output of `ls`, and if your `ls` version supports the `-p` option, you can `ls -lip | grep -v '/$'`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf since the `+` is not always available and we are only running `ls` which is not too hard on the machine I don't think it is worth it. As for hidden files, I consider listing them a feature not a bug :).

Answer (score 1):

Another find alternative:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%i %p\n"
```

Or yet another:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -ls
```

Comment: You might want to use `maxdepth 1` to mimic `ls`. Otherwise, this will find all files in all subfolders recursively.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative way using the commands `tree` and `grep`. Grep is used to filter out the directory entries:

```
$ tree --inodes -f -F|grep -v "/$"
```

#### Example

```
$ tree --inodes -f -F|grep -v "/$"|less
.
|-- [10370679]  ./a
|-- [10359494]  ./a.bash*
|   |-- [10359495]  ./alsa/alsa-info.sh*
|   `-- [10370145]  ./alsa/alsa-info.txt.v8hSmCT2Rf
|   |   |   |-- [11147371]  ./apps/apache-maven-2.0.9/bin/m2*
|   |   |   |-- [11147367]  ./apps/apache-maven-2.0.9/bin/m2.bat
|   |   |   |-- [11147368]  ./apps/apache-maven-2.0.9/bin/m2.conf
|   |   |   |-- [11147372]  ./apps/apache-maven-2.0.9/bin/mvn*
|   |   |   |-- [11147369]  ./apps/apache-maven-2.0.9/bin/mvn.bat
|   |   |   |-- [11147373]  ./apps/apache-maven-2.0.9/bin/mvnDebug*
|   |   |   `-- [11147370]  ./apps/apache-maven-2.0.9/bin/mvnDebug.bat
|   |   |   `-- [11147378]  ./apps/apache-maven-2.0.9/boot/classworlds-1.1.jar
|   |   |   `-- [11147374]  ./apps/apache-maven-2.0.9/conf/settings.xml
|   |   |   `-- [11147376]  ./apps/apache-maven-2.0.9/lib/maven-2.0.9-uber.jar
|   |   |-- [11147363]  ./apps/apache-maven-2.0.9/LICENSE.txt
|   |   |-- [11147364]  ./apps/apache-maven-2.0.9/NOTICE.txt
|   |   `-- [11147365]  ./apps/apache-maven-2.0.9/README.txt
```

The above incorporates the directory hierarchy into the lines for each file, and also makes use of the `-F` switch so that tree appends a trailing `/` to each line that's a directory. Utilizing that feature, we're able to grab any lines that now have this trailing `/` and omit them.

#### References

- [tree man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree)